# UWP/C# More efficient way of handling FileSavePicker?

Tags: c#, uwp

Ive got the following `FileSavePicker` function running on button press. I was wondering if this is an acceptable way of handling the FileSave or if there are any better practices that i should be adopting when handling save files?

```
// Save File SubScriptHere:

private async void SaveButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Text Document", new List<string> { ".txt" });
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("CSV Document", new List<string> { ".csv" });
    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
}
```

It seems really basic and seems to run perfectly fine. Im just trying to adopt good habits where possible as im still learning. Should I be handling errors or confirming if the file saves correctly etc? It just seems too barebones for me to be comfortable with what ive come up with

Comment: It looks reasonable to me.

Comment: no there isnt a more efficient way to do this, this is the default way.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if this is an acceptable way of handling the FileSave ...

Yes, it certainly is. You need to remember to take care of the file, i.e. save it somewhere, though. The `FileSavePicker` just lets the user choose the file name, extension, and storage location for a file. You could use the `FileIO.WriteTextAsync` method to actually save it:

```
private async void SaveButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Text Document", new List<string> { ".txt" });
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("CSV Document", new List<string> { ".csv" });
    StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "contents...");
}
```

Comment: Also if you want to be able to read that file again later (eg, from a most-recently-used list in your app) then you should add it to the [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Many thanks for the heads up :) I shall keep it in mind